# Print the length of the longest continuous sequence (Python)

Tags: python, iteration

Here's The [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blAg9.png):

[image]

> Read integers until -1 is input. 
>   Print the length of the longest continuous sequence of numbers where a number is  the sum of the 2 preceding numbers. Do not include the
>   first 2 numbers in the length of the sequence.

1,2,3,4,5,8,13,21,34,55,10,6,7,8,20,25,30,40,-1

1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,-1

5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,-1

[adi results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRPrZ.png)

Here is my failed attempt:

```
longest = 0
length = 2
i = int(input())
prev = i
diff = prev - i

while i != -1:
    if i - prev == diff:
        length = length + 1
        prev = i
    else:
        length = 2
        diff = i - prev
        prev = i
    if length > longest:
        longest = length
    i = int(input())
print (longest)
```

Any help solving this would be appreciated!

Comment: What went wrong with your failed attempt?

Comment: At the very least, give potential helpers the chance to copy'n'paste the sample inputs. Don't make them type of an image!

Comment: @schwobaseggl Although to be fair, you need to input every number anyway, so it's not saving *that* much time!

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'll add them in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
sequence = []
stop = False
while not stop:
    num = int(input())
    if num == -1:
        stop = True
    else:
        sequence.append(num)

longest = 0
length = 0
for i in range(2, len(sequence)):
    if (sequence[i-2] + sequence[i-1]) == sequence[i]:
        length += 1
    else:
        longest = max(longest, length)
        length = 0
```

First, I read in the sequence of integers until -1 is entered. Then, I loop through all of the numbers in the sequence apart from the first two. For each one, I check if it's the sum of the previous two numbers. If it is, I increment the variable which is keeping track of the length of the current continuous sequence (`length`). Once this sequence is finished, I recalculate `longest` as the maximum of itself and the current subsequence. This is repeated until all of the numbers in the sequence have been checked.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for an example of say ("5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,-1")

Comment: @NationzGG I've checked. You're right :( I'll check through my answer again.

Comment: @NationzGG Argghh it was a simple typo! I've fixed it now :)

Comment: @NationzGG Also, if my solution works for you, please can you accept it (click the tick) and upvote it? (so that people in the future know which solution works for you)

Comment: Yeah I tested it again and still the same issue, I'll upload an image to the post named "adi results"

Comment: I think the issue is that your function test for the pattern but does not account for the fact that the first event may not be the longest.

Comment: I was able to fix your solution by adding this code:                                            if longest > length:
    print(longest)
else:
    print(length)